# Exporting layers from PSD results in wrong colors

Tags: adobe-photoshop, colors, gimp, image-editing, psd

[I have a PSD](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_yBl-184usmSnU2M05NSUZrXzA/view?usp=sharing). Opening it or exporting it with GIMP displays the layer I'm interested in the colours [I'd expect it to have](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_yBl-184usmTVhaSWdmRVUydGs/view?usp=sharing). Exporting the layer from the PSD using PSDParse or Adobe Creative Cloud produces an image that looks "darker" in some software.

- [layer export produced by PSDParse](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_yBl-184usmNVhyclMtS001ODQ/view?usp=sharing)
- [layer export produced by Adobe Creative Cloud](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_yBl-184usmNDJmZEVzMmdya2c/view?usp=sharing)

Any idea why this is happening? Which one is really the correct colouration.

[Here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_yBl-184usmNE5sNHV3Q0p3VGs) is a PSD without the problem.

Comment: The PSD in your first link has a colour space of "CHG_02_051117". If you converted it to sRGB then all your images would probably look the same.

Comment: That seems to work! Some questions about it though; Should I just use the default GIMP options to do that? Is it lossless? Do you know of a way to batch convert PSDs into sRGB PSDs?

Comment: I'm not familiar with GIMP, but I expect it has some sort of batch-procesing option.

Answer (score 2):

The PSD in your first link has a colour space of "CHG_02_051117". If you converted it to sRGB then all your images would probably look the same.

If you have many images to process in GIMP, you can use [GIMP batch mode](https://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Basic_Batch/).

There are many guides to colour management in Photoshop available by searching for "how to color manage in photoshop". The sRGB colour space is suitable for displaying on monitors - if the images are to be printed then some other colour space might be more suitable.